# 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable nginx/1.13.3 in docker

Tags: docker, nginx

I am trying to use `jwilder/nginx-proxy: alpine` in order to start `nginx`, following is the docker run command and steps:

**Step1**:  `docker run -d -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro --name nginx jwilder/nginx-proxy:alpine`

**Step2**: Opened port `80` in the Security Group of ec2 instance, and trying to connect to `ip:80/`, but the error is as follows **503 Service Temporarily Unavailable nginx/1.13.3**

docker logs says:

```
WARNING: /etc/nginx/dhparam/dhparam.pem was not found. A pre-generated dhparam.pem will be used for now while a new one
is being generated in the background.  Once the new dhparam.pem is in place, nginx will be reloaded.
forego     | starting dockergen.1 on port 5000
Generating DH parameters, 2048 bit long safe prime, generator 2
forego     | starting nginx.1 on port 5100
dockergen.1 | 2017/08/14 13:45:44 Generated '/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf' from 4 containers
dockergen.1 | 2017/08/14 13:45:44 Running 'nginx -s reload'
dockergen.1 | 2017/08/14 13:45:44 Watching docker events
dockergen.1 | 2017/08/14 13:45:44 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'
nginx.1    | ec2-xx.xx.xxx.xx..ap-xyz-5.compute.amazonaws.com xx.xxx.xxx.x -     "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 615 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36"
nginx.1    | ec2-xx.xxx.xxxx.xxx.ap-xyz-5.compute.amazonaws.com xx.xx.xx.xxx  "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 503 615 "http://ec2-xx.xxx.xx.xx.ap-xyz-5.compute.amazonaws.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36"
```

Answer (score 2):

`jwilder/nginx-proxy` doesn't make a lot of sense ran alone. The script behind the magic check other containers environment variables and generate the according rules to reverse proxy from `hostname from another container as defined in env var : port defined the same way` to the said container & port.

The key here is "hostname from another container". Nginx won't proxy-forward you when you're trying to connect with an IP like you said.

Here's an example from jwielder/nginx's README.md from its github repository

```
version: '2'

services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro

  whoami:
    image: jwilder/whoami
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=whoami.local         <================
```

Run this, edit your hosts file (something like `sudo vim /etc/hosts`) add `[ec2ip] whoami.local` then open your browser for http://whoami.local, that'll work just fine.